# Issues with CSS checkbox checked not working in nav ul

Tags: css, checkbox

I have a checkbox like this,

```
 <nav>
        <div id="center">
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>

            </ul>

            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
        

        </nav>
```

but, the check box doesn't work on the check box selector and I don't know why.
this is my css nav and check box.

```
 nav ul{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background: #2c3e50;
            top: 47px;
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 0;
            transition: all .5s;
    
        }
    #check:checked ~ nav ul {
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: where is your `nav ul` ?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a related note, `~` is for the general successor sibling (meaning the element comes after this one).

Since your `ul` has the fixed position, move it after `label` tag.

Also remove `nav` from `#check:checked ~ nav ul` in css style.

```css
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  top: 47px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}
 
#check:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="center">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </label>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```